# Действия при спаме GET запросов

Tags: get

Здравствуйте! Я сейчас учу NodeJS, сделал сервер на NGINX, запустил сайт. И, по этому, сайту в папку uploads, через формы поиска на других сайтах начали приходить GET запросы. Сперва это не мешало. Но потом число запросов начало расти по прогрессии. И в итоге выедается вся оперативка, которой и без того мало (сервер дешёвый). Подскажите, как правильно поступить в такой ситуации? Как убрать эти ненуждые запросы? Что читать, какие мануалы смотреть? Спасибо!

Приходят запросы такого рода:

```
::ffff:134.0.112.216 - - [23/May/2017:14:55:57 +0000] "GET /images/bg.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 90323 "http://www.hack-it-up.ru/" "Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/6.5.26560/28.2555; U; ru) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10"
::ffff:134.0.112.216 - - [23/May/2017:14:55:57 +0000] "GET /images/header.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2650 "http://www.hack-it-up.ru/" "Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/6.5.26560/28.2555; U; ru) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10"
::ffff:134.0.112.216 - - [23/May/2017:14:56:07 +0000] "GET /blogs/iilacudagi8/61.html HTTP/1.1" 404 4309 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
::ffff:134.0.112.216 - - [23/May/2017:14:57:09 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 4253 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.137 YaBrowser/17.4.1.718 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
::ffff:134.0.112.216 - - [23/May/2017:14:59:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4093 "-" "BitrixCloud Monitoring/1.0"
::ffff:134.0.112.216 - - [23/May/2017:15:00:26 +0000] "GET /gifts/ HTTP/1.1" 404 4233 "http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=1430.iPb-6qbbR8K_x0rpaazfdZS7yopure13ibg6itS-X-MVjwOxOjkFbxkN1fj9d5tF.b1b16ec7276181fbc3550c4ad760ff99d8634ba0&uuid=&state=_BLhILn4SxNIvvL0W45KSic66uCIg23qh8iRG98qeIXmeppkgUc0YHRNgn3KsbHJbmUkku86_mY&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxdk5wZE1KcDhHeFpzYXpDemoybmxyemJPcTlsWFgwN3h6eFBaY3ZseE82WW9pRmVHUnJjNGNmQnNzdUtrWG9EbGkxTUxTcWhQa3Z5YUZhVVpfUWNteEE&b64e=2&sign=8915f722e8d4b845edcc4418f16ea69e&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ7IXge4WdYJQaYgAYq7Jarroc8MJXVpFDQdqbEqAbkMrbTFR7Rgb3Vy6qBQNxGVSYYIjX-Oq52f5cUjwXBrTrmSfaChT7v1xwh7r4rbARm0AHL_h8TVD0XmtBsD2vIOEsH81bvJCpcZdurbr4xp81t-&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kp5uQozpMtKCXmyCrj7VrKuHbdUcgeLYm9HRPFf6RhfbQS7dccbAIvh6Z5bhZ5nF5rZCAUaI9xtKWNG6W3Mbx7Ag&l10n=ru&cts=1495550206643&mc=3.89107749495" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; MDDCJS)"
::ffff:134.0.112.216 - - [23/May/2017:15:02:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4093 "-" "BitrixCloud Monitoring/1.0"
::ffff:134.0.112.216 - - [23/May/2017:15:02:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4093 "-" "BitrixCloud Monitoring/1.0"
::ffff:134.0.112.216 - - [23/May/2017:15:03:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4093 "-" "BitrixCloud Monitoring/1.0"
::ffff:134.0.112.216 - - [23/May/2017:15:04:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4093 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexMetrika/2.0; +http://yandex.com/bots mtmon01e.yandex.ru)"
::ffff:134.0.112.216 - - [23/May/2017:15:04:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4093 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexMetrika/2.0; +http://yandex.com/bots mtmon01e.yandex.ru)"
::ffff:134.0.112.216 - - [23/May/2017:15:08:14 +0000] "GET /upload/iblock/1f7/1f7fc5d905ef47115618ceb188f8052f.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 4425 "http://formulax-ag.ru/upload/iblock/1f7/1f7fc5d905ef47115618ceb188f8052f.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36 OPR/45.0.2552.812"
::ffff:134.0.112.216 - - [23/May/2017:15:08:15 +0000] "GET /upload/iblock/c0d/c0d53131b91acca7fd8da68b97bd7d2d.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 4425 "http://formulax-ag.ru/upload/iblock/c0d/c0d53131b91acca7fd8da68b97bd7d2d.jpg" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36 OPR/45.0.2552.812"
::ffff:134.0.112.216 - - [23/May/2017:15:09:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4093 "-" "BitrixCloud Monitoring/1.0"
```

Comment: да что-то не так уж и часто запросы приходят

Comment: как вы поняли, что не хватает оперативки?

Comment: ну это просто фрагмент такой. а так бывает и почаще значительно запросы идут. когда работаю с сайтом пробую страницу открыть не могу иногда выскакивает ошибка. плюс, сегодня пришло оповещение на почту мне что не хватало оперативки. а сайты-то пустые